# Problems starting vnstat installed with brew

Tags: homebrew, services

After installing vnstat with homebrew:

```
brew install vnstat
```

and opening it, i got following error:

```
Error: Failed to open database "/usr/local/var/db/vnstat/vnstat.db" in read-only mode.
The vnStat daemon should have created the database when started.
Check that it is configured and running. See also "man vnstatd"
```

It seems, that the daemon is not running.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to start the service via brew:

```
sudo brew services start vnstat
```